# Flutter: Show different icons based on value

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a list of objects each with an icon property as shown here:

```
List<Map<String, String>> _categories = [
    {
      'name': 'Sports',
      'icon': 'directions_run',
    },
    {
      'name': 'Politics',
      'icon': 'gavel',
    },
    {
      'name': 'Science',
      'icon': 'wb_sunny',
    },
];
```

I then have a widget that I am using inside of a ListView.builder() widget. Currently I am displaying a statically chosen icon to show with the text in my list. My question is how can I use the icon property in my objects to dynamically pick the icon that gets shown for each individual list item?

```
  Widget _buildCategoryCards(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
      child: Card(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.directions_run),
              SizedBox(width: 20.0),
              Text(_categories[index]['name']),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: You can use index to decide which icon needs to be shown and then you can also use operator like `index == 0 ? showThis: elseThis`

Comment: How do I do that for each one though since it's a list?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change your `List` to store an `IconData` instead of a `String`:

```
List<Map<String, IconData>> _categories = [
    {
      'name': 'Sports',
      'icon': Icons.directions_run,
    },
    {
      'name': 'Politics',
      'icon': Icons.gavel,
    },
    {
      'name': 'Science',
      'icon': Icons.wb_sunny,
    },
];
```

Then, call the `IconData` from your build method:

```
  Widget _buildCategoryCards(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
      child: Card(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(_categories[index]['icon']),
              SizedBox(width: 20.0),
              Text(_categories[index]['name']),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

---

Note that this is not useful (even not effecient) to use a `Map` to do what you want. You should use a custom class:

```
Class Category {
  String name;
  IconData icon;

  Category(this.name, this.icon);
}
```

And then replace your `List` with this:

```
List<Category> _categories = [
    Category('Sports', Icons.directions_run),
    Category('Politics', Icons.gavel),
    Category('Science', Icons.wb_sunny),
];
```

finally in your Widget:

```
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(_categories[index].icon),
          SizedBox(width: 20.0),
          Text(_categories[index].name),
        ],
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. Why isn't it useful / efficient to use Map in this situation?

Comment: Short answer: A `Map` is meant to manage a collection of key/value pair data. It is kinda the same as a `List`, but instead of accessing data through an index, you access it through a key (which can be of any type you want). So in your case, you have a List containing 3 collections of 1 item each. There is no need to have a collection if you have only 1 item in it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the icon identifier from Icons class in the list instead of storing the text. But if you want to create a mapping from icon label to icon identifier.

Comment: @UdeshUK Answers like this are best suited as comment.