# How to convert a Flutter String to Icon value

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, I'm  getting Icon value from json as a String.

I got following error when I tried to use that value

```
error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [hippo] lib\screens\dynamic_list.dart:71)
```

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "MenuItems": [
    {
      "id": 419701,
      "icon": "MdiIcons.account",
      "name": "account"
    },
    {
      "id": 419702,
      "icon": "MdiIcons.currencyUsd",
      "name": "Funds"
    },
    {
      "id": 419703,
      "icon": "MdiIcons.home",
      "name": "home"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254963/flutter-show-different-icons-based-on-value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use Icon class constants according to official Flutter docs. (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html#constants)

example:`IconData(0xf518, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')`

also you can generate custom images to font icon ([Generate to font](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select)). save ttf file in assets. pass unicode data (like "e90a").

example:

```
Icon(IconData(int.parse('0x${e90a}',
    fontFamily: 'family name given in the link above'));
```

Comment: Hi how do i find out the unicode data for the icon?

Comment: Dart has a builtin function to get the unicode value from a char, so for example when you want to display a pound/hash sign as an icon, you can write this: `Icon(IconData("#".codeUnitAt(0)))`

Comment: Check the Icon class constants: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html#constants

Answer (score 22):

You can do it by using Icon class constants according to official Flutter docs.

```
Icon(IconData(61668, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'));
```

Check more Icon class constants here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html#constants

[image: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html#constants]

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question. Please explain more.

Comment: By using Icon class constants, we can use it on JSON as Integer or as String.

Comment: Please add that explanation to the answer itself, by [edit]ing. Also please consider demonstrating how to do that in code (because users more readily upvote answers with code....).

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for the guidance <3

Comment: There seems to be an update on 24/06/2020 where these codes don't match the icons anymore: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75633 
Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Comment: @user3705905 even I'm facing similar issues due to the recent update and the `IconData.codePoint` values stored in database are now more showing different values.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out by @user3705905 and as mentioned in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75633 using the hexadecimal or `IconData.codePoint` value won't work any more. In order to overcome the issue and to store references of the icon's  `IconData` you can use below solution using map (for example):

```
Map<String, IconData> iconsMap = {
   'add_shopping_cart': Icons.add_shopping_cart,
   'calendar_view_week_rounded': Icons.calendar_view_day_rounded,
   'call_end_outlined': Icons.call_end_outlined,
   'call_made': Icons.call_made,
};
```

Later you can simple use the map key in and later get the Icons data.

Answer (score 3):

use flutter_remote_icon

```
var remoteIconData = new RemoteIconData("material://Icons.add"); // -> native material icons remotely (dynamically)  

return RemoteIcon(icon: remoteIconData);
```

https://github.com/softmarshmallow/remote-ui/tree/master/flutter/packages/flutter_remote_icon

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_remote_icon

Answer (score 3):

I create a simple class for that.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HelperIcons {

  static Map<String, int> materialIcons = <String, int> {
    'ten_k': 0xe52a,
    'ten_mp': 0xe52b,
    'eleven_mp': 0xe52c,
    'twelve_mp': 0xe52d,
    'thirteen_mp': 0xe52e,
    'fourteen_mp': 0xe52f,
    'fifteen_mp': 0xe530,
    'sixteen_mp': 0xe531,
    'seventeen_mp': 0xe532,
    'eighteen_mp': 0xe533,
    'nineteen_mp': 0xe534,
    'one_k': 0xe535,
    'one_k_plus': 0xe536,
    'twenty_mp': 0xe537,
    'twenty_one_mp': 0xe538,
    'twenty_two_mp': 0xe539,
    'twenty_three_mp': 0xe53a,
    'twenty_four_mp': 0xe53b,
    'two_k': 0xe53c,
    'two_k_plus': 0xe53d,
  };

  static Map<String, int> materialIconsWithDirection = <String, int> {
    'arrow_back': 0xe5a7,
    'arrow_back_ios': 0xe5a8,
    'arrow_forward': 0xe5af,
    'arrow_forward_ios': 0xe5b0,
    'arrow_left': 0xe5b1,
    'arrow_right': 0xe5b2,
    'assignment': 0xe5b9,
    'assignment_return': 0xe5bc,
    'backspace': 0xe5d6,
    'battery_unknown': 0xe5e3,
    'call_made': 0xe627,
    'call_merge': 0xe628,
    'call_missed': 0xe629,
    'call_missed_outgoing': 0xe62a,
    'call_received': 0xe62b,
    'call_split': 0xe62c,
    'chevron_left': 0xe652,
    'chevron_right': 0xe653,
  };

  static IconData getIconData(String iconName) {
    iconName = iconName is String ? iconName.toLowerCase().trim() : null;

    if (iconName == null || iconName.isEmpty) {
      return null;
    }

    if (materialIcons.containsKey(iconName)) {
      return IconData(materialIcons[iconName], fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');
    }

    if (materialIconsWithDirection.containsKey(iconName)) {
      return IconData(
          materialIconsWithDirection[iconName],
          fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons',
          matchTextDirection: true
      );
    }

    return null;
  }

  static bool isExistIcon(String iconName) {
    iconName = iconName is String ? iconName.toLowerCase().trim() : null;

    if (iconName == null || iconName.isEmpty) {
      return false;
    }

    if (materialIcons.containsKey(iconName) || materialIconsWithDirection.containsKey(iconName)) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

Usage :

```
if (HelperIcons.isExistIcon(iconString)) {
  Icon(HelperIcons.getIconData(iconString))
}
```

I can't put all the class code here. because this post limited to 30k characters.

Answer (score 3):

I used material icon to solve this problem

import 'package:material_design_icons_flutter/material_design_icons_flutter.dart';

```
 icon:  Icon(MdiIcons.fromString('sword'))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "MenuItems": [
    {
      "id": 419701,
      "icon": "0xf2dc",
      "name": "account"
    },
    {
      "id": 419702,
      "icon": "0xf2dc",
      "name": "Funds"
    },
    {
      "id": 419703,
      "icon": "0xf2dc",
      "name": "home"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
Icon(IconData(int.parse(_dynamicListMenu[index].icon),
              fontFamily:'Material Design Icons',
              fontPackage:'material_design_icons_flutter'),color: Colors.white, size: 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove this '' Apostrophe , because icon data should not be a string

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it in your class from string to IconData
like this:

```
final IconData iconData; 
className({Key? key, required this.iconData}) : super(key: key);
.
.
.
.
icon: Icon(widget.iconData)
```